# add array of polylines as distinct lines in googlemaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-maps-api-3

I'm working with the googlemaps api.  I've looked for answers to this Q, found some similar questions but none that seem to work for me.

I want to add an array of polylines to a googlemap as distinct lines with distinct colors, not one continuous line.

I'm pulling my lat lng coordinates from a json file.  The array of polylines (themselves arrays of lat lng coords) is variable in length.

I can't figure out how to run my polyline.setMap then run it again until there are no more sets of polylines left in the array.

Here is the code in questions:

```
paths = [];
allStrms = [];  
$.getJSON("json/basin/"+file+"", function(json) { 

// iterate through each year array in JSON
for (i = 0; i < json.year.length; i++) {

//only grab data from 2013
if(json.year[i]["@attributes"].id == '2013') {

//iterate through the latLng array in each storm object
for (p=0; p < json.year[i].storm.latLng.length; p++) {

//get each pair of lat / lng coordinates from latLng array

var path = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(json.year[i].storm.latLng[p].latitude), parseFloat(json.year[i].storm.latLng[p].longitude));

//push to paths array 
$.each(path, function(){
        paths.push(path);
  });
}

//push all paths to allStrms array
allStrms.push(paths);


for(p=0; p < json.year[i].storm.latLng.length; p++) {

function addPolyline() {

    for(t=0;t<allStrms.length;t++) {

        polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: allStrms[t],
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: 'yellow',
            strokeOpacity: 1,
            strokeWeight: 2
          });

       }

       polyline.setMap(map);

      //end for loop
     }


//end for loop - json.year[i].storm.latLng
    }

//end if condition for year 2013
 }


// end initial for loop
}


  addPolyline();

 //end $.getJSON
});
```

How do I set it up to run my polyline then stop, run again, stop, etc... until all lines are on map and distinct?

Here is the code in action.  The page loads an array of polylines as a jumble of lines on page load.

http://wx.wpri.com/html/testing/ht/bt-v2.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: please define what is in the var paths and in the var allStrms

Comment: Could you please indent your code? (both in the question and on your live page; at least if you would like assistance, I can't tell where your `getJSON` success function ends...)

Comment: A [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue in your question would also be helpful.

Comment: sorry about that.  Let me clean up/remove extraneous code and then I'll edit the code in the question to include a complete $.getJSON function with my problem.

Comment: My guess is that your issue has nothing to do with the `$.getJSON` call, rather is an issue with how you are processing the returned data in the callback function (you are putting all the paths into a single array), so you probably just need an example that processes more than one polyline from JSON in the correct format.

Comment: Why do you have a function definition inside a loop that doesn't do anything? `addPolyline()`

Answer (score 0):

1. push each lat/lng pair for a single polyline into a single array:

   ```
   if (json.year[i]["@attributes"].id == '2013') {
       var path = [];
       //iterate through the latLng array in each storm object
       for (p = 0; p < json.year[i].storm.latLng.length; p++) {
           //get each pair of lat / lng coordinates from latLng array
           var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                 parseFloat(json.year[i].storm.latLng[p].latitude), 
                 parseFloat(json.year[i].storm.latLng[p].longitude)
               );
           path.push(point);
       }
   ```

2. push that path onto your allStrm array (and create it's polyline):

   ```
   //push all paths to allStrms array
   allStrms.push(path);
   var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
           path: path,
           geodesic: true,
           strokeColor: 'yellow',
           strokeOpacity: 1,
           strokeWeight: 2
       });
    polyline.setMap(map);
   ```

complete $getJSON function:

```
$.getJSON("http://wx.wpri.com/html/testing/ht/json/basin/NA.min.json", function(json) { 
  var json = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
  // iterate through each year array in JSON
  for (i = 0; i < json.year.length; i++) {
    //only grab data from 2013
    if (json.year[i]["@attributes"].id == '2013') {
        var path = [];
        //iterate through the latLng array in each storm object
        for (p = 0; p < json.year[i].storm.latLng.length; p++) {
            //get each pair of lat / lng coordinates from latLng array
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(json.year[i].storm.latLng[p].latitude), 
                  parseFloat(json.year[i].storm.latLng[p].longitude)
                );
            path.push(point);
        }
        //push all paths to allStrms array
        allStrms.push(path);
        var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: path,
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: 'yellow',
                strokeOpacity: 1,
                strokeWeight: 2
            });
         polyline.setMap(map);
    }
  }
  //end $.getJSON
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/afsq8w7m/1/)